# How to get response header in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a nodejs project, I use request module to submit restful request and get response. (here is the module link: https://github.com/request/request)

Following the instruction, I should be able to get the response header by calling `response.headers['']`,  however, seems it doesn't work, when I try to call `var contentType = response.headers['Content-Type']`,  the `contentType` is `undefined`. (When I use postman, I could get Content-Type from the response).  Anyone knows what's wrong?

This is the instruction from the site:

```
var request = require('request')
request(
    { method: 'GET'
    , uri: 'http://www.google.com'
    , gzip: true
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {
      // body is the decompressed response body
      console.log('server encoded the data as: ' + (response.headers['content-encoding'] || 'identity'))
      console.log('the decoded data is: ' + body)
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In node, the headers are accessed by using lowercased names, so using `response.headers['content-encoding']` is correct.

Your code snippet currently works for me and displays 'server encoded the data as: gzip.'

Comment: The code says content-encoding and the question says content-type. Both work here so long as lowercase is used.