# Accessing response headers using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, uservoice

I'm having a problem right now which I can't seem to find a solution to.

I'm using [Uservoice's NodeJS framework](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uservoice-nodejs) to send some requests to UserVoice regarding Feedback posts. A problem I've run into are ratelimits so I want to save the header values [`X-Rate-Limit-Remaining`, `X-Rate-Limit-Limit` and `X-Rate-Limit-Reset`](https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/api/getting-started) locally. I've made a function for updating and getting that value and am calling it like this:

```
var content = "Test"
c.post(`forums/${config.uservoice.forumId}/suggestions/${id}/comments.json`, {
      comment: {
        text: content
      }
    }).then(data => {
      rl.updateRL(data.headers['X-Rate-Limit-Limit'],data.headers['X-Rate-Limit-Remaining'],data.headers['X-Rate-Limit-Reset'])
```

When running this code I get the error `Cannot read property 'X-Rate-Limit-Limit' of undefined`.

This is not a duplicate, I've also tried it lowercase as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700283/how-to-get-response-header-in-node-js) but had no luck either. Thanks for helping out!

EDIT:
The function takes the following parameters:

```
module.exports = {
    updateRL: (lim, rem, res) {SAVING STUFF HERE}
}
```

It is defined in the file `rates.js`and is imported in the above file as `const rl = require('../rates')`.